# Which one is preferred in the Python print statement ( + or , )?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I just started learning Python recently. I am just wondering which one is the correct format/preferred in the print statement in Python. Does it matter which one I use since the output is the same?

```
print("Your age is" + age)
```

or

```
print("Your age is",age)
```

Comment: `print(f"Your age is {age}")`

Comment: `+` wouldn't work if `age` was a number: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe hi i'm coding in python 3 and using + worked for me

Comment: @John then `age` isn't a number, I'm saying it wouldn't work *if it was*.

Comment: There's also a difference if you are passing a `sep` argument to `print`, as `"Your age is" + age` is a *single* argument, while `"Your age is", age` is *two* arguments that will be "joined" using the `sep` argument.

Comment: (Even your example would demonstrate that difference, as the default value of `sep=' '` is used. For `age == 17`, your first outputs `Your age is17`, while the second outputs `Your age is 17`.)

Answer (score 3):

In that case, it does not really matter which one you use, **if** the data type of `age` is string, because the syntax is correct and the program will run.

**But,** if you should face different data types then you have to be careful which one you choose, because otherwise you'll run into an error.

The best & safest solution is to use **formatted strings**.

As a formatted string your code would look like:

```
   print(f"Your age is {age}")
```